# Terminal Server/Xenapp6 on boot autostart application for specific user

Tags: terminal-server, xenapp

On a Windows 2008 r2 Xenapp6 server I have a user that logs in via RDP with his domain account, he is local administrator.

If the server reboots I would like his start up apps/scripts to run.

A simply way would to have his user automatically login at boot but this seam to be an ugly way of solving this. This would also lock the console. At he moment he is the only user who uses this machine so I might do this but there must be a better way.

Comment: Task Scheduler is the answer. You can run program on starup as any user.